# How to uninstall the ntfs-mac software?

Tags: macos

I installed the ntfs-mac, but later I remove it into trash, I think I had deleted it completely, but now I can see a popup window that tell me me trial version of ntfs-mac had expried, so I think I didn't delete it completely, who can tell how can I do to not pup up this window again?

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty easy, you need to download again the Trial version of NTFS for Mac (if you do not have it anymore in your *Downloads* folder).

Now in *Finder*, go to your *Downloads* folder and double click on the NTFS for Mac file. The file should be mounted now. You will see that there is a `Uninstall NTFS for Mac` program, simply double click it.

That's it. For more information you could refer to the [user manual](http://download.paragon-software.com/doc/NTFS4Mac10_en_manual.pdf), especially the chapter "De-installing the Driver" page 21.